# Converting a set of parameterized classes to an IntMap

Tags: scala

Wondering if someone can tell me the correct way to convert the Set below to an IntMap.

```
    case class A[T](i: Int, x: T)
    val set: Set[A[_]] = Set(A(1, 'x'), A(2, 3))

    val map: IntMap[A[_]] = IntMap(set.map(a => a.i -> a))
```

gives me

```
type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Set[(Int, A[_$19]) forSome { type _$19 }] required: (scala.collection.immutable.IntMapUtils.Int, A[_])
```

And

```
    val map: IntMap[A[_]] = IntMap(set.map(a => a.i -> a).toMap)
```

Gives me:

```
Cannot prove that (Int, A[_$19]) forSome { type _$19 } <:< (T, U).
    - not enough arguments for method toMap: (implicit ev: <:<[(Int, A[_$19]) forSome { type _$19 },(T, 
     U)])scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U]. Unspecified value parameter ev.
    - polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : [T, U]scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U] required: 
     (scala.collection.immutable.IntMapUtils.Int, A[_])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IntMap.apply`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.IntMap$@apply[T]%28elems:%28scala.collection.immutable.IntMapUtils.Int,T%29*%29:scala.collection.immutable.IntMap[T]) accepts a varargs param, so you need to call it like this:

```
val map: IntMap[A[_]] = IntMap(set.map(a => a.i -> a).toSeq: _*)
```